# How to generate markup ids for dynamic divs?

Tags: php

How to generate ids for dynamic div tags using php or jQuery?

example: php generates 36 divs, how to set each div to be unique in the range 1 to 36?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 37; $i++)
{
   echo "<div id='div-$i'></div>";
}
```

Edit: 2D version, even though you have one, I didn't realise this is what you wanted.

```
for($x = 1; $x <= 36; $x++)
{
    for($y = 1; $y <= 36; $y++)
    {
        echo "<div id='div-$x-$y'></div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note though, a valid html id must start with a character A-Z, a-z.

Comment: @Chris, that's why I used `div` as a prefix :)

Comment: Its not working, because each dynamic div gets the same property- 1

Comment: Tnx, this solution worked for me :) <?php for($i = 0, $z = 10; $i < $z; $i++) { ?>

Comment: Oh, sorry, did you want it to be two dimentional like, 1-1, 1-2, 2-1, 2-2?

Comment: Yes :) How to set break when $z=10?      After 10, its start loop agen

Comment: Well I just edited, change 36 to what you want, it will make essentially a grid to the x and y you specify

Comment: Anyway its repets from 36. I think its because i have php script for dynamic grid:  <?php
for ($k = 2; $k >= -3; $k--)
{
   for ($j = -3; $j <= 2; $j++)
   {
      $st_x = ($k + 3) * 58 + ($j + 3) * 58;
      $st_y = (3 - $k) * 25 + ($j + 3) * 25;
     
    

?>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You can use PHP:

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i <= 36; $i++) { ?>
      <div id="div<?php echo $i; ?>"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

**or** JavaScript:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 36; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'div' + i;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Okey this solution worked for me :) <?php for($i = 0, $z = 10; $i < $z; $i++) { ?>

Comment: @Nation Then mark it as the solution: click the grey tick on the left hand side.

Comment: How to set brake? After 36, its start loop agen.

Comment: Do you know PHP break manual? How to set break when $z=10? After 10, its start loop agen from 1-10 and again, and again... How to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=1;i<=36;i++){
  echo "<div id='my-div-$i'>".$divContents[$i]."</div>";
}
```

Comment: Tnx, this solution worked for me :) <?php for($i = 0, $z = 10; $i < $z; $i++) { ?>