# Assign unique ID to div as created and then reference with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic-data, unique-id

I am brand new to php and a beginner with jQuery. I have a php page that is populated with data from a mySQL table.  What I am trying to achieve is for the h3 that contains "View Job" to have a unique id assigned to it, as well as the div that prints out the job description.  Then, I would like to reference these with jQuery so that if someone clicks View Job, only the description for that job will show.  I hope this makes sense.

I tried this with classes and of course all the job descriptions revealed themselves when any View Job was clicked.

I tried the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770594/how-to-generate-markup-ids-for-dynamic-divs), but this ended up with 36 "View Job" links on my page, and I need to assign the unique ID to the h3 and div as they are created.

I am open to suggestions for another way to achieve what I'm looking for - basically to hide/collapse each description as the user clicks on View Job for each job.

here is my code:

```
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        .job-post{border-bottom: 1px solid red; padding: 0; margin: 10px 0;}
        h3, p{padding: 0; margin:0;}
        .view-job{cursor: pointer;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            $("div#job-details").css("display" , "none");
                             $("h3#view-job").click(function() {
                                $("div#job-details").css("display" , "block");
                            });

                        });
         </script> 
        <?php 
         // Connects to your Database 
         mysql_connect("xx", "xx", "xx") or die(mysql_error()); 
         mysql_select_db("lcwebsignups") or die(mysql_error()); 
         $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM openjobs") 
         or die(mysql_error()); 
          ?>
         <div id="job-container"> 
          <?php 
         Print ""; 
         while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
         { 
         Print "<div class='job-post'>"; 
         Print "<h3>Position / Location:</h3> <p>".$info['jobtitle'] . ", ".$info['joblocation'] . "</p>";
         Print "<h3 id='view-job'>View Job:</h3> <div id='job-details'>".$info['jobdesc'] . " </div>"; 
         Print "</div>";
         }  
         ?>
        </div><!--//END job-container-->
```

Comment: Try using the jQuery .next() selector to display the DIV next to the clicked element. You can also use the ` ^= ` (starts with) selector to filter a jQuery selector so that only the `<h3>` elements whose ID starts with ___ will be fired.  See my detailed (working) answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Assign the `classNames` instead of `id's`

Then use the **this** context to select your `div` which will only search for the one in the context and not all the divs

```
$("h3.view-job").on('click',function() {
    $(this).next("div.job-details").css("display" , "block");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.job-details{display:none;} 
.job-post{border-bottom: 1px solid red; padding: 0; margin: 10px 0;}
h3, p{padding: 0; margin:0;}
.view-job{cursor: pointer;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     // Please hide this class on CSS
     // $("div.job-details").css("display" , "none");
     $("h3.view-job").click(function() {
        // you ned to use this keyword
        // it is very important when you use javascript or jquery
        // this keyword only pick element on which you click
        $(this).parent().find(".job-details").show();
    });

});
   </script> 
    <?php 
     // Connects to your Database 
     mysql_connect("xx", "xx", "xx") or die(mysql_error()); 
     mysql_select_db("lcwebsignups") or die(mysql_error()); 
     $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM openjobs") 
     or die(mysql_error()); 
     ?>
     <div id="job-container"> 
     <?php 
     // First of all Please use echo instead of Print
     echo ""; 
     while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
     { 
         echo "<div class='job-post'>"; 
         echo "<h3>Position / Location:</h3> <p>".$info['jobtitle'] . ", ".$info['joblocation'] . "</p>";
         // you can't use id multiple time in a same page so instead of id use Class
         // if you want to use id then you have to generate uniq id
         // check below I generate id --> I don't know your database field that's why I used jobId
         echo "<h3 class='view-job' id='job".$info['jobId']."'>View Job:</h3> <div class='job-details'>".$info['jobdesc'] . " </div>"; 
         echo "</div>";
     }  
     ?>
    </div><!--//END job-container-->
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want (tested okay). Just replace your mysql login info and the example should work.

I completed your job-details div (it was missing the data from php), but what you were really looking for is the jQuery code.

When an `<h3>` tag **whose id begins with the characters `view-job`** is clicked, the jQuery click event handler will:

- re-hide all divs **whose id starts with the chars `job-details`**
- display the next div in the DOM tree

---

CODE:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .job-post{border-bottom: 1px solid red; padding: 0; margin: 10px 0;}
    h3, p{padding: 0; margin:0;}
    .view-job{cursor: pointer;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div[id^='job-details']").css("display" , "none");

        $('h3[id^="view-job"]').click(function() {
            $("div[id^='job-details']").hide(500);
            $(this).next('div').show(500);
        });

    });
 </script> 

 <?php 
    // Connects to your Database 
    mysql_connect("xx", "xx", "xx") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("lcwebsignups") or die(mysql_error()); 
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM openjobs") or die(mysql_error()); 

        $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM openjobs") or die(mysql_error());
  ?>

<div id="job-container"> 

<?php 
    echo "<br>"; 
    while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc( $data )) { 
        echo "<div class='job-post'>"; 
        echo "<h3>Position / Location:</h3> <p>".$info['jobtitle'] . ", ".$info['joblocation'] . "</p>";
        echo "<h3>View Job:</h3> <div id='job-details'>".$info['jobdetails']."</div>"; 
        echo "</div>";
    }
 ?>

 </div><!--//END job-container-->
```